# Как делать последовательные ajax/fetch запросы правильно?

Tags: javascript, jquery

именно дождаться ответа предыдущего и потом только запускать следующий

Comment: async/await и вперёд

Comment: непонятен вопрос. в чём именно проблемы?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, теор вопрос

Comment: [это не дубликат ли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/554290/178576)?

Answer (score 0):

вам нужно изучить тему `async/await` например **[здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/async-await)** (т.к. для одного ответа это обширная тема). Это позволяет делать асинхронные запросы, дожидаясь ответа от предыдущего. Фрагмент кода из статьи выше:

```
async function showAvatar() {

  /*****************************************/

  // запрашиваем JSON с данными пользователя
  let response = await fetch('/article/promise-chaining/user.json');
  let user = await response.json();

  // запрашиваем информацию об этом пользователе из github
  let githubResponse = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${user.name}`);
  let githubUser = await githubResponse.json();

  /*****************************************/






  // отображаем аватар пользователя
  let img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = githubUser.avatar_url;
  img.className = "promise-avatar-example";
  document.body.append(img);

  // ждём 3 секунды и затем скрываем аватар
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));

  img.remove();

  return githubUser;
}

showAvatar();
```

Comment: а без них?.без async/await

Comment: без них будет неправильно :D